# How install Flutter & Android Studio in Different Location?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, sdk

I'm starting learning Flutter as a beginner. but after installing Flutter and android studio, my local disk c has less than 800MB. when I run it, the whole screen was stuck and after a few minutes, it show an error message about disk space.

can I install Flutter and android studio in different partitions? (when I install SDK, it cost me more than 4GB). I have more than 700GB in my Local Disk D. but as a mistake, I was done earlier, I only give 200GB space to the C partition. Right now I can't reset my computer.

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: uninstall both then reinstall. When installing it should ask you where you want to install

Comment: Download flutter sdk and put it in your D drive. (delete older flutter installation somewhere in C drive). open android studio and it will ask for flutter sdk location, provide that new D drive location. I think you have to manually set some system variables for that, may be

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, when you install AndroidStudio, choose the location to the drive you want.

When you load and unpack Flutter, choose where you want to save it.

Then when you make a new project, point the path to the location where you saved Flutter.